# PHP to jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have tried to change this PHP code to jQuery or JavaScript but does not work.

I'm new to jQuery and JavaScript

Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php
    // Set timezone
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

    // Start date
    $date = '2009-11-06';
    // End date
    $end_date = '2010-11-31';

    while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
        echo  date("M Y", strtotime($date)) . "<br/>";
        $date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 month", strtotime($date)));
    }
    date("M Y", strtotime($date));
```

Here is the Javascript Code:

```
<script>
    function getDates() {
        var effectiveDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+3 months", strtotime('1-1-2017')));
        alert(effectiveDate);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried

Comment: You should try first. Search for date/time methods in JavaScript, try to use them, if fails, share your code and you'll get some help here. P.S You need pure JS here, jQuery has nothing to do with this.

Comment: may be it is better you show us your js code to so we can show you the mistake instead of a working result

Comment: <script>
        function getDates() {

            var effectiveDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+3 months", strtotime('1-1-2017')));
            alert(effectiveDate);
        }
    </script>

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: You'll have to explain what you're trying to do (what's the intent of that PHP snippet?) before anybody will bother coming up with a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html

```
<div id='outputdates'>

</div>
```

Javascript

```
// Start date
newdate = new Date('2009-11-06');
// End date
end_date = new Date('2010-11-31');

var theDiv = document.getElementById("outputdates");
while (newdate <= end_date) {
    theDiv.innerHTML += newdate.getMonth()+' '+newdate.getFullYear()+ "<br/>";
    newdate = new Date(newdate.setMonth(newdate.getMonth() + 1));
}
theDiv.innerHTML += newdate.getMonth()+' '+newdate.getFullYear()+ "<br/>";
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aquadk/1pcLhsd0/10/

Comment: Thank Your Sir @ReneLykkeDahl